# Populating values for form input elements using servlet

Tags: servlets, user-interface, rendering

I needs to populate values for listboxes , textboxes .. almost all the form input elements from my servlet . Because sending the object to the JSP page and populating the values for the input elements there (using any tag libraries JSTL) i found it difficult.

Is there anyway for setting all the Input Element values from the servlet itself? For example if i needs to set the value for textfield , then in my servlet

```
TextFieldBean tf = new TextFieldBean("userName");
tf.setValue("Test");
```

In my jsp page

```
<input type="text" name="userName">
```

Comment: Is this any framework available to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what all MVC frameworks (that I know about) allow doing. Here's an example with Stripes:

```
// in the Stripes action:
public Resolution displayForm() {
    this.userName = "Test";
    return new ForwardResolution("/displayForm.jsp");
}

// in the JSP
<s:form beanClass="com.foo.bar.SubmitFormAction" method="post">
    User Name : <s:text name="userName"/>
</s:form>
```

MVC frameworks have their own learning curve, but they offer huge services (data binding being one of them). Pick one and learn: Stripes, Spring MVC, Play, ... there are dozens of them. I like Stripes for its simplicity and good design.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a MVC framework for some reason, use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils).

```
BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap());
```

That's it. You only need to ensure that the bean property names exactly match the request parameter names.

MVC frameworks however offer more other advantages next to applying request parameters, such as to conversion, validation, event listening, executing actions, dynamic rendering, etcetera. So instead of cobbling several separate libraries together to make the life easier, you could just go ahead for only one all-in-one MVC framework. Next to the request based MVC frameworks as mentioned by JB Nizet, there are also component based MVC frameworks which is far more abstracted (as to eliminating HTML/CSS/JS boilperlate), such as [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: Let me explain more about my scenario. I will call webservices to receive the data from the database . For example if i am retrieving Person data from webservices,i needs to send this data(may be just xml or JAXBObject)to JSP page, there i need to populate the values for my input elements. In case if the  person edit page have the Country Listbox then i needs to send Country XML values (getting it from Countrywebservice) and populate value.Here only i am finding it difficult.So that if any option available like i can populate values for my input elements from Java class itself.I hope its clear